# Nonzero solutions to $\mathbb E\left[e^{\theta X}\right] = 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with $\mu=\mathbb E[X]\ne0$ and that $X$ has a finite moment generating function on some open interval containing $0$. Then for what $\theta\ne0$ does the following equation hold?
$$\mathbb E\left[e^{\theta X}\right] = 1. $$

The book I am reading (*Stochastic Processes* by Ross) says "We shall suppose that such a $\theta$ exists (and is usually unique)" without justification. This statement does not seem obvious to me. For example, if $X$ has exponential distribution with mean $\mu$, then 
$$\mathbb E\left[e^{\theta X}\right] = \frac{\mu^{-1}}{\mu^{-1}-\theta}=1 $$
has only the solution $\theta=0$, while if $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \theta^2)$,
$$\mathbb E\left[e^{\theta X}\right] = e^{\mu\theta + \frac12\sigma^2\theta^2}=1,$$
has the solution $\theta = -\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}$. So under what conditions does this equation have nonzero solution(s)?

Edit: The map $x\mapsto e^{\theta x}$ is convex, so Jensen's inequality yields
$$e^{\theta\mu}\leqslant\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}]=1 $$ and hence $\theta\mu<0$. This means $\theta$ and $\mu$ must have opposite signs.

Comment: If $X$ has constant sign, for example $P(X>0)=1$ as in your first example, then $E(e^{\theta X})>1$ for every positive $\theta$ and $E(e^{\theta X})<1$ for every negative $\theta$, or vice versa, hence there is no hope. On the other hand, if $P(X>0)$ and $P(X<0)$ are both positive then $E(e^{\theta X})\to\infty$ when $\theta$ converges to either bound of the interval of definition hence it suffices to know that $E(e^{\theta X})<1$ for some $\theta$ to conclude... and this is the case when $E(X)\ne0$ and $E(e^{\theta |X|})<\infty$ for at least some positive $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Did's comment,  if $\mathbb P(X>0)=1$ then $\mathbb P(\theta X>0)=1$ for $\theta>0$ so $\mathbb P(e^{\theta X}>1)=1$ and $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}]>1$. By the same logic, $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}]<1$ for $\theta <0$.

If $\mathbb P(X<0)=1$ then by symmetry we see that $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}]<1$ when $\theta>0$ and $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}]>1$ when $\theta<0$.

If $\mathbb P(X>0)$ and $\mathbb P(X<0)$ are both positive, then $\mathbb E[e^{\theta X}]\to\infty$ when $\theta$ converges to a boundary point of its region of convergence. So $\mathbb E[e^{\theta|X|}]$ is finite for some $\theta>0$, we conclude by continuity of $\exp$ that there exists $\theta^\star\ne0$ such that $\mathbb E[e^{\theta^\star X}]=1$.